# Cmake and Qt error when compiling

Tags: compiling, qt

I hope this is not a duplicate. I am trying to compile a program (Kid3) on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I run cmake command I get the below error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Multimedia"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5MultimediaConfig.cmake
    qt5multimedia-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Multimedia" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Multimedia_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Multimedia" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:289 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried to find a solution for the error and the suggestion I found was to install qttools5-dev which I did.

However, I still get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the [qtmultimedia5-dev package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qtmultimedia5-dev) installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .cmake files for Qt components live in the corresponding -dev package, so for this one you need to install `qtmultimedia5-dev` as @steeldriver correctly pointed out:

```
sudo apt install qtmultimedia5-dev
```

Notice how the package names are quite different from the names of the Qt modules: *Qt5Multimedia* vs. *qtmultimedia5*.

Please notice that the Kid3 project also provides links to  PPAs and official Ubuntu repositories where you can install ready-built binary packages directly:

- https://kid3.kde.org/ (Project home page)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is more than useful. Problem solved.